# microcontroller bring-up

Tags: microcontroller, pcb

I'm in the process of assembling a microcontroller PCB design.  It's essentially just a breakout board.  I'm trying to think of the best way to test the board after assembly.  My first thought is to try to program the board with a test program.

Am I on the right track?  It seems so obvious, but board programming is still non-trivial.  I'm used to moving in more predictable, piecemeal type steps whenever possible.  Are there any less complicated tests I should be performing that could give me more insight?

One of the issues I'm facing is that the micrcontroller has an LGA style package.  With the pins hidden + hand assembly, it's difficult to trust that all the connections are made properly.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're on the right track although I'd check for shorts between power and gnd before powering it up.   If there's an external crystal that should be enabled by default you can scope it and see if it's oscillating.

Your first test will be seeing if you can even talk to it over jtag, in other words if the tool can even see the part.

If that works you can move on to trying to blink an led or toggle an I/O pin to see if it's working.

Comment: Oh and probably worth testing power and gnd for shorts on your bare board too, especially if you didn't pay for electrical test at your fab.

Comment: Great ideas. I've been rushing through this, and can't believe I didn't think check anything like this.  Thanks.  I'll probably do a short test for all the pins against each other too.

Comment: @getonup not only should you test for power and ground shorts, please test for voltage regulation and the voltage on each of your rails, to ensure they are properly regulated (without load, as in, your MCU isnt operating yet). Your regulators may regulate without load, but when things start happening they may screw up which is harder to test for, but while it's running a program you should use an oscilloscope and ensure it's not dipping down causing brownouts